# Generates a CSV file from all the outputs of your team’s scripts using Git BASH

Tags: shell

I created a Github repo for my team and my teammates uploaded their scripts in different programming languages. Please does anyone know how to create a bash script that generates a CSV file from all the outputs of your team’s scripts

Answer (score 0):

Most scripting languages support a shebang line as the first line, which specifies the interpreter to be used. That means you can just invoke them as regular applications. For compiled languages you will have to invoke the necessary compiler first and then run that program.

You can start from something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f outputs.txt
for file in programs/*; do
    echo -n "$file," >> outputs.txt
    case "$file" in
        *.cpp|*.c|*.cc)
        build=$(mktemp -d)
        cp "$file" "$build"
        base=$(basename "$file")
        program=${base/.*}
        (cd "$build"; CFLAGS="-O2" CPPFLAGS="-O2" make "$program")
        if [ -f "$build/$program" ]; then
           ( "$build/$program" || echo "CRASH" ) >> outputs.txt
        else
          echo "COMPILE_ERROR" >> outputs.txt
        fi
        ;;
        *)
        chmod +x "$file"
        ( "./$file" || echo "CRASH" ) >> outputs.txt
        ;;
    esac
done
```